# How to remove NUL in the end of NSString?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Here is a code how I get video card name in OS X:

```
- (NSString *)getGPUInfo
{
    NSString *graphics = @"";

    // Get dictionary of all the PCI Devicces
    CFMutableDictionaryRef matchDict = IOServiceMatching("IOPCIDevice");

    // Create an iterator
    io_iterator_t iterator;

    if (IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,matchDict,
                                     &iterator) == kIOReturnSuccess)
    {
        // Iterator for devices found
        io_registry_entry_t regEntry;

        while ((regEntry = IOIteratorNext(iterator))) {
            // Put this services object into a dictionary object.
            CFMutableDictionaryRef serviceDictionary;
            if (IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(regEntry,
                                                  &serviceDictionary,
                                                  kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                  kNilOptions) != kIOReturnSuccess)
            {
                // Service dictionary creation failed.
                IOObjectRelease(regEntry);
                continue;
            }
            const void *GPUModel = CFDictionaryGetValue(serviceDictionary, @"model");

            if (GPUModel != nil) {
                if (CFGetTypeID(GPUModel) == CFDataGetTypeID()) {
                    // Create a string from the CFDataRef.

                    graphics = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(__bridge NSData *)GPUModel encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                }
            }
            // Release the dictionary
            CFRelease(serviceDictionary);
            // Release the serviceObject
            IOObjectRelease(regEntry);
        }
        // Release the iterator
        IOObjectRelease(iterator);
    }

    return graphics;
}
```

It returns me a string: "Intel HD Graphics 3000NUL"

What's wrong with a code? I also tried another encoding "NSUTF8StringEncoding" but no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, the data object for the "model" entry in the IO registry dictionary
has a trailing NUL byte, and that is preserved when converting to `NSString`.

A simple method to get rid of trailing NUL characters in `NSString` is to convert
it to an UTF-8 string and back

```
graphics = @([graphics UTF8String]);
```

`@(<UTF-8 String>)` is a "boxed expression" (equivalent to `stringWithUTF8String`)
and stops the conversion at the first NUL byte.

Comment: I did with:
                    NSRange range = NSMakeRange([graphics length] - 1, 1);
                    graphics = [graphics stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];

Comment: @Sergio: I tested your code on my MacBook, and there were *two* devices found in the loop. The first had the trailing NUL but the second not. Your code removes the last character even if it is not NUL.